# Coverting a basic search string to a regex

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have a search string like:

*"Hello [NAME], how are you today? I am fine."*

If I were to use a regex pattern to search text I would have to convert it to something like (assuming that '\ ' is a valid regex search for a single space):

*"\Hello\ \[NAME\],\ how\ are\ you\ today\?\ I\ am\ fine."*

Now before I go off and try to write a function to do this myself is anyone aware of something that already does this sort of conversion? (Eclipse does something a bit like this; it converts all its searches into regular expressions before searching, even if you're not setting the search pattern to be a regex).

I'm targetting C# in this instance but feel free to add for other languages as other people might be interested in a similar thing for Java, Python et al.

Comment: You do not need to espace spaces in regex (unless you set the IgnorePatternWhitespace flag).

Comment: @Jens You don't need to, but there's also no harm in escaping spaces even if the flag isn't set. If you're writing a method to do the escaping then you probably want to escape the spaces so that you don't have to care whether IgnorePatternWhitespace will be set when your returned pattern is used.

Comment: If I didn't, then:

`"Hello \ \ \ \ [Name]...."` (That is with more than one space).

Would match, which is not what I want.

Comment: Jens is right - the pattern `a b` only matches the exact string `a b`, it doesn't match `a      b`. If IgnorePatternWhitespace is set then the pattern `a b` matches only the string `ab` and the pattern `a\ b` matches the string `a b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Regex.Escape(string)` will return a Regex pattern that matches the supplied literal string.

Specifically, it escapes `\*+?|{[()^$.#` and white space.

Comment: Looks perfect - I will give it a whirl.